# Show specific text only in outlook mail client

Tags: html, email, outlook, inline, show

I can't find a way to show specific text only in outlook mail clients. Out company have new email signs with worker images. But in older versions of Outlook the images don't appear just a red cross, and that is ugly. My idea is to only show a line of text like "please accept images". This line of text only shown on Outlook, not in other mail clients. I tried a lot of options like:

```
<!--[if mso]>

    <p></p>

<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if (IE)]>

    <p></p>

<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<div style=“mso-hide:all”>
  
</div>
```

I also tried to work with: display:block !important or overflow: hidden

Maybe one of you guys have a solution?

Thanks for now!

Arjan

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Arjan.

I do not think this can be done, unfortunately.
If the Outlook client has images turned of by default there is indeed an icon showing a broken image, but next to the image there is also a text with instructions how to enable images in the email

If the width/height parameters are missing on the image, this text is not shown properly. One solution if you want to show that text is to increase the width of the image to min 250px. If that works you might need to edit the profile images as well so that there are a white space next to the "real" image to make sure it is displayed properly within the (ex) 250px width.

Another solution might be to inline the image in the emails, but that is generally worse (attachments in all outgoing emails) than getting the image from remote.

Comment: Hi Henkealg, Thank you for your solution(s). Do I have to give the image in the code that 250px width or is just edit/scale the image and upload it enough? My second question is can I change that message text?:)

Comment: Or can I add a text to my email signature that only shows up on outlook clients?